# to be produced vs which is produced

Tags: grammar

A)Vehicle is first fully electric Suv ***to be*** produced in Turkey.

B)Vehicle is first fully electric Suv ***which is*** produced in Turkey.

Sentence A and sentence B are the same in the meaning? which one is more idiomatic? what is the diffrence (if exists) between the sentences?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/first), it is normal to use a to-infinitive for the meaning that you require:

> **first** noun (THING/PERSON)
>
> B1 [ S ]
>
> the first person or thing to do or be something, or the first person or thing mentioned:
>   [ + to infinitive ] *She was one of the first to arrive.*

Note that your sentence needs a couple of determiners:

> **the/this** vehicle is **the** first fully electric SUV to be produced in Turkey.